# bokeh background fill color

Tags: python, bokeh

Below is a screenshot of the plot that I have. The plot on the left is the one I generate, and the plot on the right is the same plot that I have panned to illustrate where the background_fill_color is getting applied.

The color labelled as (x) is what I'm looking to apply in the area labelled (y).

**Added the exact code below now**

```
    TOOLTIPS = [("(x,y)", "($x, $y)")]
    p = figure(tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,save",
               title=TITLE,x_range=x, 
               y_range=(<<my_y0_range_1>>,<<my_y0_range_2>>), 
               x_axis_label='time',y_axis_label='index',
               plot_width=150, plot_height=100,toolbar_location="below",
               tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
    p.background_fill_color = <<mycolor>>
    p.line(x, y0, legend_label="values", line_width=1)

    p.extra_y_ranges = {"Vol": Range1d(start=<<my_y1_range_1>>,end=<<my_y1_range_2>>)}
    p.line(x, y1, legend_label="my 2nd Y axis", line_color="red",y_range_name="Vol")
    p.varea(x=x,y1=<<my_range_1>>,y2=<<my_range_2>>,alpha=0.3)
    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Vol"), 'right')
```

What attribute should I be using to mark the area labelled (y) with the color of my choice, thanks?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full code? `background_fill_color` works just fine for me, so it seems like the (y) area has something plotted that covers the whole plot. After all, it has gray color which must come from somewhere.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, added now, thanks. When I size the plot to say 1000,500 for instance, the background color starts to become a little visible. However, when I reduce the plot size to 150,100 (which is what I need), then I run into the background color problem I mentioned above.

Comment: That's not full code - I cannot run it to reproduce the behavior. When you ask a question, StackOverflow asks you to provide a minimal _reproducible_ example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Including all the imports and data - so that people that are trying to help you can just run it as is and don't have to guess and do additional work.

Comment: You're correct - if you had attempted to reproduce the problem with fewer xgrid data points, you would not have successful. My bad, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more research and came up with the following:

- the number of data points on the x axis is approx. 340.
- the plot size (height x width) is 100 x 150

In the above scenario (and ones similar to this), the background_fill_color appears to become irrelevant because there are 340 xgrid lines that overlay it. Suppressing the gridlines brings out the background_fill_color in this case.

```
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
```

or

```
p.xgrid.visible = False
```

Hopefully, this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem where you have a relatively large'ish set of data points vis-a-vis the plot size. Either enlarge the plot size, or alternatively suppress the gridlines (would seem like the grid lines are set to some sort of a 'show' mode by default, as opposed to 'enable/show' them only if I want to). I'm not complaining about the default behavior and am a big fan of bokeh and its simplicity. Salut to the folks who came up with it and who continue to contribute to it.